# mouseenter and removeClass not working with hidden objects

Tags: jquery, removeclass, mouseenter

I have two divs, and I want the second to appear when the first one is hovered over. I've done a similar thing before, but the same code isn't working now.

```
<div class='button blog'>                 
    <h2>Blogs</h2>
</div>

<ul id='blogs' class='hidden'>
    <p>James</p>
    <p>Jeremiah</p>
    <p>Peter</p>
    <p>Thomas</p>
</ul>
```

My jquery code is simple so far

```
$('.blog').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.blogs').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

I do have the main function setup and a line running the document on the ready mark. I even have some other jquery code that is working, which does basically the same thing, and runs off the same principles. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your selecting it via *ID* you have to use `#`

```
$('#blogs').removeClass('hidden');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick and straight-forward response! I had actually just figured this out and face-palmed myself mentally :)

Answer (score 3):

in addition to spokeys answer, i assume, that you also want to hide it again, on mousleave.
the easiest way would be the show() and hide() function. those won't work, if the element itself is set to hidden via css.

so first of all, remove the hidden class (which i suppose would hide the element via css) from your html.
your script should look like that:

```
$("#blogs").hide();

$(".blog").hover(function(){
        $("#blogs").show();
    },
    function(){    
        $("#blogs").hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: :D Amazing! Thank you so much, this will certainly clean up my jquery a bit. I knew about .show() and .hide() but I couldn't figure out how to start them off hidden.